PublicNTP vs NTP Pool
There are two providers for NTP servers which are not associated with big IT (like Cloudflare, Google, MS, etc) and nor with any government entities (NIST, US Navy, etc). They are PublicNTP and NTP Pool.
What is the difference between these two service providers? Is one better than the other? What are the advantages that NTP Pool has over Public NTP and vice versa?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The major differences that I see are:

The NTP Pool has servers that exist, while the PublicNTP servers do not seem to actually exist – I chose 5 servers from the PublicNTP map and none of their hostnames resolve to an IP address (of either version). I assume that the project ended shortly after 2019.

Functionally, the NTP Pool is a pool, in the sense that a single DNS entry will automatically select out of all available servers (i.e. the DNS server makes decisions for you, prioritized by geolocation), whereas PublicNTP only offers individual DNS entries for single servers.
The lack of a single 'pool' DNS name would lead to additional administrative burden should that server go down, as well as its location changing or new more-preferred servers being added.

Organizationally, all servers within the NTP Pool exist independently of the pool, i.e. they are set up and managed by various individuals or organizations (ISPs, etc.) that only join the pool later, whereas the entirety of PublicNTP is operated by the same people.

In fact, the PublicNTP blog claims that all of its servers are submitted for inclusion to the NTP Pool, making its service (if there is still any) strictly a subset of the NTP Pool service.



Thanks your answer helps. Are there any other alternatives apart from PublicNTP and NTP Pool but which are not associated with big IT?

Run your own. Buy a GNSS receiver that supports the satnav signals of your favorite faction and connect it to chrony/ntpd. That's how most of the NTP Pool works.

Generally, small NTP server operators who want to run it as a public service do so by deliberately joining the NTP Pool, whereas those who don't, are most likely to keep their services private to their local network or customers. If there is a public NTP server that isn't participating in the NTP Pool, I'm not going to do the searching.
